# Brackets input CSS

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am developing a phonegap App for Android containing a form.

**HTML** :

```
<input class="holo">
```

Here problem is that the `input` tag has not applied with CSS style in my Samsung Galaxy Pocket (4.0.4). But in Moto G (KitKat 4.4.2) works fine!!

**CSS** I used:

```
input.holo {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
font-family: "Roboto", "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 8px 6px 8px;
display: block;
outline: none;
border: none;
background: bottom left linear-gradient(#09c, #09c) no-repeat, bottom center linear-gradient(#09c, #09c) repeat-x, bottom right linear-gradient(#09c, #09c) no-repeat;
background-size: 1px 6px, 1px 1px, 1px 6px;
}

input.holo:disabled{
background: #e8e8e8
}

input.holo:disabled:hover{
background: #e8e8e8
}
input.holo:hover, input.holo:focus {
background: bottom left linear-gradient(#09c, #09c) no-repeat, bottom center linear-gradient(#09c, #09c) repeat-x, bottom right linear-gradient(#09c, #09c) no-repeat;
background-size: 1px 6px, 1px 1px, 1px 6px; 
}
```

Thanks.

**PS: In Chrome works fine!!
http://jsfiddle.net/GLVc8/**

Comment: what do you mean by saying "doesn't work' It doesn't show up, text can't be entered, it displays wrong or what ?

Comment: The problem is that the input hasn't style

Comment: first of all, remove :hover state as its totally useless in mobile solutions.

Comment: Yes, I know it and this isn't the solution!